# Происхождение фамилии Герцен

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Наткнулась в сети на такое обсуждение:

[image]

Так все-таки, какое происхождение у фамилии Герцен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На википедии есть ответ на данный вопрос. Но давайте сначала подумаем вот о чем - действительно, фамилия Герцен на слух кажется немецкой и вполне явственным кажется происхождение от слова Herz (сердце). Но всякое в жизни бывает. Тем более, что есть анекдот:

> - как тебя звать?
> - Го-го-го-го-го-го-го-го-го-го-ги.
> - Ты что, заика?
> - Нет, мой отец был заика, а паспортист - идиот :))

Так вот, википедия утверждает, что Герцен был внебрачным сыном, поэтому у него могли быть определенные трудности, если б он получил фамилию матери или отца. Или наоборот - это возможно в то время было отдельной непростой задачей. Не уверен. История говорит, что фамилию Герцен придумал его отец, потому что это был "сын его сердца". Эта версия мне кажется весьма правдоподобной.